# Leaflet VideoOverlay controls

Tags: leaflet

In one of my projects, I have to integrate video on a leaflet Map. I didn't use the extend layer method because the video can have arbitrary dimension and should behave as other elements's map. I'm using a `videoOverlay` element to do so.

But now I have a problem, how to provide a proper way for the users to controls the video? I try to add the attribute `controls` inside the html video tag but the controls don't appears.

So I think that my only solution now is to make an external Leaflet controls right ?
Is it possible to have the controls on the video, as classical html video tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the [`getElement()` method of `L.VideoOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#videooverlay-getelement) to get the relevant instance of [`HTMLVideoElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement).

Then, since `HTMLVideoElement` is a subclass of [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), it has a [`controls` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controls) you can modify.

Put together it should look like:

```js
var overlay = L.videoOverlay( /* stuff */ ).addTo(map);

var el = overlay.getElement();

el.controls = true;
```

or even:

```js
var overlay = L.videoOverlay( /* stuff */ ).addTo(map);

overlay.getElement().controls = true;
```

Please note that the `HTMLVideoElement` instance only exists after the `L.VideoOverlay` has been added to a `L.Map`.